# convert JSONresponse to NSDATA or NSDICTIONARY in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsjsonserialization

I get a response from a public test api in swift as a JSONarray:

```
func getFlightData(airportCode: String, minutesBehind: String, minutesAhead:String){
    let securityToken: String = "Basic YWFnZTQxNDAxMjgwODYyNDk3NWFiYWNhZjlhNjZjMDRlMWY6ODYyYTk0NTFhYjliNGY1M2EwZWJiOWI2ZWQ1ZjYwOGM="
    var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]
    headers["Authorization"] = securityToken
    let parameters: Parameters = ["city": airportCode, "minutesBehind" : minutesBehind, "miutesAhead" :minutesAhead]
            Alamofire.request("https://api.qa.alaskaair.com/1/airports/"+airportCode+"/flights/flightInfo", parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)

    }
```

I have used almofire in swift4 to achieve this operation.

Should I convert this JSONArray to NSData or NSDictionary? and How?
Do I have to use JSONSerealization?

Comment: if let result = response.result.value {
                let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                print(JSON)
            }

Comment: Gives a SIGABRT error. Also, should I convert it into NSDATA or NSDictionary? I get back a JSONArray as a response to the web service

Comment: This is Swift. Do not use `NSData`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSxxxx`. Use `Data`. Use a Swift dictionary or array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using Alamofire as your network requester, So it is not necessary to convert the response object to JSON object or Data object. The library itself will provide to parsed JSON object. So check the below sample code to check the JSON object.

```
    let urlString = "https://......"
    let securityToken: String = "Basic YWFnZTQxNDAxMjgwODYyNDk3NWFiYWNhZjlhNjZjMDRlMWY6ODYyYTk0NTFhYjliNGY1M2EwZWJiOWI2ZWQ1ZjYwOGM="
    var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]
    headers["Authorization"] = securityToken
    let parameters: Parameters = ["city": 100, "minutesBehind" : 60, "miutesAhead" :0]
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { (response) in
        if let jsonObject = response.result.value{
            print("response.result.value \(String(describing: jsonObject))")
        }

        if let jsonObject = response.value{
            print("response.value \(String(describing: jsonObject))")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let urlPath: String = BASE_URL + uri

    let url = URL(string: urlPath)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.addValue("no-cache", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
        .responseJSON { response in

            print("S-E-R-V-E-R  C-A-L-L  C-O-M-P-L-E-T-E-D")

            switch response.result {

            case .success:

                if let json = response.result.value {

                    var data = [String: AnyObject]();

                    if let dict = json as? [String: AnyObject]{
                        // Dictionary found
                        data = dict;
                    }
                    else if let list = json as? [AnyObject] {
                        // Array found
                        data = ["data":list as AnyObject];
                    }          
             }

            case .failure(let error):

                print("status code: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                failure(error as NSError);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use following to achieve this.

[ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)

[AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper)

[Moya-ObjectMapper](https://github.com/lyft/mapper)